# Unable to access the key of a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to access a key of a dictionary here

```
{'application_id': '467377486141980682',
 'attachments': [],
 'author': {'avatar': '25cb9058944599f9f1ba15279f9e4a8f',
            'bot': True,
            'discriminator': '0000',
            'id': '964810500611375104',
            'username': 'Sparky99'},
 'channel_id': '790967460039491644',
 'components': [],
 'content': '73561',
 'edited_timestamp': None,
 'embeds': [],
 'flags': 0,
 'id': '976330290698006528',
 'mention_everyone': False,
 'mention_roles': [],
 'mentions': [],
 'pinned': False,
 'timestamp': '2022-05-18T03:48:00.642000+00:00',
 'tts': False,
 'type': 0,
 'webhook_id': '964810500611375104'}
```

I can access all these except the username.

When I run `dic.get("username")` , it returns `none` like if doesn't exists but all other elements are accessible to me using `dic.get()`

Note: Tell me if I need to add some more info to the question.

Comment: The username key is nested in a dictionary in the author key.  Try `dic.get('author').get('username')`

Comment: x["author"]["username"] should work

Comment: per latest edit, and also as mentioned in comments, `dict.get('username')` should **indeed** return None. I don't see anything as wrong in particular with that, in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`username` isn't a key in that dictionary. There's a key called `author` whose value is a dictionary and in there, you can find `username`.

Comment: ```dict.get('author').get("username")``` worked for me